# Remove the possibility of the user to select a file

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to remove the possibility to choose a file from the following code. 
I mean, I have a button that, when clicked, gives to the user the possibility to load a file into the program. However I would like to load by default a file called "animation.txt".

I don't want to force the user to be in a particular path, but I want to totally remove the possibility to choose a file. I already know the path and the name of it, and the program should only read it.

I have tried to play with the code, but I get this error:

```
  Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

This is my code:

---- .JS FILE -----

```
  document.getElementById('saveLoader').onchange = function() {

        keyframeTheta = [];
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
          // By parts
          var parts = this.result.split('|');
          for (var i = 1; i < parseInt(parts[0]) + 1; i++) {
            var allValues = parts[i].split(',');
            var someTheta = [];
            for (var f = 0; f < allValues.length + 10; f++) {
              console.log(allValues[f]);
              someTheta[f] = parseFloat(allValues[f]);
            }

            console.log(someTheta[0]);
            keyframeTheta.push(someTheta.slice());
          }

        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
        toastr["success"]("Animation loaded successfully. Hit Run", "Animation");
      }
```

---- HTML FILE ------

```
           <li class="nav-item">
              <label class="nav-link" style="color: white" type='file' accept='text/plain' for="saveLoader">
                 <input style="display:none" type="file" name="file" id="saveLoader"/>
                 <i class="now-ui-icons files_paper"></i>
                 <p>Load Animation</p>
              </label>
           </li>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? What what's happening, and what do you want to happen. As concise as possible would be best. Thanks!

Comment: The file selection is part of the operating system and is not scriptable from the browser.

Comment: @Virx I have a .txt file inside the same folder of this code. I need to read that particular file, without opening the file selection. The user doesn’t have to do anything. When he launch the code, the .txt file has to be already loaded.
I use this code to load an animation that is stored inside a txt file, I want that the user only presses run, without previously load the animation.

Comment: @Pierfrancesco so you're wondering how to fetch a file with JavaScript?

Comment: You probably want to perform an AJAX request to a server side script, which would read the file and respond with the JSON-formatted contents that you would then use to build your `keyframeTheta` array.

Comment: @Virx I guess yes.. I mean I just want to remove the current method of getting the file. The program, when launched, read that and only that file. The user doesn’t have to choose anything.